# How to schedule a job using python and crontab?

Tags: python, django, cron

I would like to send an automated mail using python, django and crontab. So I did the following things.

Created a cron_tab.py(which is inside the folder home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/cron_tab.py) which looks like below:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage,EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'testmailing@gmail.com', 'robert@gmail.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

And using terminal I entered in to crontab by issuing the below command

```
crontab -e
```

I scheduled the task like

```
* 1 * * *  /home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/cron_tab.py
```

But I didn't mail receive. What am I doing wrong? Please Somebody help me. After changing the file mode I get the following error and pasted the traceback

```
 myhome@myhome:~/django/myapp/registration$ ./cron_tab.py
 from: can't read /var/mail/django.core.mail
 ./cron_tab.py: line 3: subject: command not found
 ./cron_tab.py: line 4: from_email: command not found
 ./cron_tab.py: line 5: to: command not found
 ./cron_tab.py: line 6: text_content: command not found
 ./cron_tab.py: line 7: html_content: command not found
 ./cron_tab.py: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 ./cron_tab.py: line 8: `msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email,
 [to])'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your `cron_tab.py` didn't read django configuration from `setting.py`.  What happens then you run this script from the shell?

Anyway you should consider to use [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/) for this task.

Comment: @@catavaran: I updated my post along with the traceback. Please have a loot at it.

Comment: You are trying to run your script as a shell script.  To run as a python add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your script.

Comment: @@catavaran:I added #!/usr/bin/env python as first line, but still I get the same error.

Comment: @@acatavaran: I changed my first line as #!/usr/bin/python. changed cron_tab.py as executable. But still error remains the same

Comment: What if the python is in virtualenvironment ? How to add the first line of script

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using a Python script that is not probably an executable and it doesn't declare the executable in the first line of the line.

You have two options:

1) Add the python interpreter in the cron call (in this example the python interpreter is in /usr/bin/python:

- 1 * * *  **/usr/bin/python** /home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/cron_tab.py

2) Made the python script executable (2.1+2.2)

2.1.- Made the file executable

$ **chmod +x /home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/cron_tab.py**

2.2.- Edit the file and in the first line declare in the interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage,EmailMultiAlternatives
```

Comment: @@Juan Fco. Roco: I tried yours option as well. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that your Python script works executing it separately.
2. Check that your Python script can be executed via running `./cron_tab.py` on the `/home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/` directory. If this does not work execute: `chmod +x /home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/cron_tab.py` anywhere on your command line, making sure your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` pointing to your Python interpreter.

If you are not using any other feature from Django (like models, querysets, etc), this approach for sending the email should work as a separate script not knowing anything from Django. On the other hand, if using some of the Django features you will have two approaches to run this script:

a) As a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) => If using this approach, I recommend you creating a separate script for the crontab which only will run:

`cd /home/myhome/django/`

`python manage.py <your_command>` (On this case: )

b) As a Python script loading your Django configuration => You can run your script using directly.

Comment: @@avenet: I get this error from: can't read /var/mail/django.core.mail when I run ./cron_tab.py from /home/myhome/django/myapp/registration/. Could you Please tell me what I have to change now.

Comment: @questionspost Can you paste the whole traceback on your question?

Comment: @@avenet: what do you mean by your_command in python manage.py <your_command>? I m sorry I dont get you. Coukd you please explain me

Comment: @@avenet: I pasted the traceback in my post. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @questionspost Just put this line as the first line of your Pyhon script `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @questionspost Adding your management command allows you to create a Django command, that's the way Django creates: syncdb and even runserver commands, so you can create your own. In this case you could create one command named cron_tab and run it via python manage.py  cron_tab, for doing [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales) on management commands.

Comment: @@avenet: :I added #!/usr/bin/env python as first line, but still I get the same error

Comment: @questionspost Did you run chmod+x on your file?

Comment: @questionspost Also, you can try setting `#!/usr/bin/python` as your first line. If this approach does not work run the command which python and let me know in the comments.

Comment: @@avenet: yes, I did run chmod+x cron_tab.py. my which python gives /usr/bin/python.

Comment: @@avenet:I changed the first line as #!/usr/bin/python. changed file as executable. Still error remains the same

Comment: Do you have your django project in virtual environment ?